# How to load symbols in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: symbols, pdb-files

When I am debugging my app I see messages:

> cannot find or open the PDB file

I seem to remember being able to specify the location of the PDB file while debugging the app. How can I do this? I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: OK , I figure out how : Debug - Windows - Modules and then right click on the dll to load the pdb . Problem now is that it tells me "A matching symbol was not found in this folder." Even though the pdb and dll names match .

Comment: I added the pdb files to the same directory as the dlls and then they were loaded successfully .

Comment: You should answer your question instead of commenting on it. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 18):

## Adding Symbols Location

Open Settings: **Tools->Options -> Debugging -> Symbols** and add directory, where your .PDB files are located.

[screenshot of Visual Studio Interface where this menu located](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CI644.png)

You can add custom path, like for each project, and also you can edit common path, where Visual Studio will save all .pdb cache.

## Making post-build script

I made in each project post-compile event, which copy all .pdb to one folder, by this i have all in one place. But you can store it separately, which i found not so convenient, as it require each time edit list of locations.

**Example of post-debug script to copy .pdb and .dll to Symbols cache location:**

```
xcopy /Y /R "$(TargetDir)$(ProjectName).pdb" "D:\VS_CACHE\"
xcopy /Y /R "$(TargetDir)$(ProjectName).dll" "D:\VS_CACHE\"
```

## Solving problem if symbols not found

*When you in debug mode, and for some reason symbols not found, it can be because of multiple reasons:*

1. You have .pdb in Symbols cache, but it's outdated *(you can get if this a case, if you put breakpoint in code and hover it)*
2. You have multiple .dll which use this part of code *(you can get if this a case, if you put breakpoint in code and hover it)*
3. Symbols not loaded, in this case you can check it by going to: **Debug-> Windows -> Modules** and trying to load needed module.

[screenshot of Visual Studio interface Modules -> Load Symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eU5qV.png)

### Making Debugging more easy:

To re-attach VS Debugger to running application, i recommend to use this free Visual Studio add-on (support VS 2015):

**ReAttach**: visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8cccc206-b9de-42ef-8f5a-160ad0f017ae

It will save you a lot of time! :)