# cannot find or open PDB file, debugging native code

Tags: c#, c++, excel, debugging

I have a code running that successfully register Excel AddIn using C# Automation and talks to C++ though C# layer

```
// Tools -> Create GUID -> Register Format
namespace MyExcelAddins
{
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual), ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("6F89542F-3DAC-471F-86DD-145F5E456968")]

    public class MyExcelFunctions : AddInRegistrator
    {
        [DllImport(@"C:\Users\Ilya\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\UnmanegedTester\x64\Debug\")]
        public static extern double AddNumbers(double a, double b);

        public double SampleAdd(double a, double b)
        {
            double res = AddNumbers(a, b);
            return res;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the view of my solution where C++ project I added from another directory.

[image: solution explorer view]

I was able to debug C# code and now I want to try to debug the C++ part. I set the debug property of C# project to

[image: C# project debug properties]

and when click run, the error I got is

[image: error when running]

If I uncheck "Enable Native Code Debugging", I do not have the error but of course cannot debug C++. My guess I'm missing something in the settings. Please let me know if anyone has an idea how to fix that.

If I continue debugging I can hit breakpoint in C# but not in C++

[image]

Comment: Debugging imported libraries can be tricky even if you own them. I think you need to manually add the PDB of the C code since VS sees to _actual_ link between the projects. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17634266/how-to-load-symbols-in-visual-studio-2012 
Keep in mind you can also use `C++/CLI` which works very well with native debugging and the C# code wouldn't need to use `import` or any of that.

Comment: The simplest way to do this is to right-click the UnmanagedC project and select "Set as StartUp Project".  Right-click again > Properties > Debugging, set the Command property to excel.exe.  You now only have the unmanaged debugging engine active when you press F5.  If you still have breakpoint problems then use Debug > Break All and Debug > Windows > Modules.  Do note that this DLL can never get loaded if you use the 32-bit version of Excel.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion guys. I marked below answer as correct one. Only thing I had to do is to continue debugging. Even though break point was telling that it did not load any symbols but code indeed hit it when running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message is telling you that you don't have debug symbols for `excel.exe`, which is not surprising since it is a Microsoft program.  You can continue debugging, and your code (which should have debugging information) will still be debuggable.  For example, you can set a breakpoint in some of your code that will be called by Excel and the debugger will stop on it when it is reached.

Comment: If I continue debugging I can hit break point in C# but not in C++ and I want to be able hit breakpoints in both languages.

Comment: @ilyaw77 Enabling Native debugging should allow for debugging the C++ code, although it won't be visible until the code in question is loaded, which might not be until you try to call `AddNumbers` from within `SampleAdd`.

Comment: Thanks 1201ProgramAlarm. You were right. If I simply ignore the message and continue debugging it indeed hit break point!